# Aligning a button on bottom right of screen ionic html

Tags: javascript, html, css, ionic-framework

I am trying to get my button to float at the bottom right of the screen and not change position when other objects change on the screen. Here is what I have so far:

```html
<head>
  <style>
  .button-float{
    z-index: 12;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 15px;
  right: 15px;
   border-radius: 50% !important;
}
  </style>
</head>
<body ng-app="App">
<ion-header-bar align-title="center" class="bar-positive">
  </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content class="has-header" overflow-scroll="false">
        <div>
             <a ng-repeat="equipment in equipment" class="item item-thumbnail-left" ng-click="goToEquipDetail(equipment)">
              <img src="resources/{{equipment.Photo}}">
              <h2>Item Name: {{equipment.ItemName}}</h2>
              <p>Serial Number: {{equipment.SerialNumber}}</p>
              <img style="position: absolute; right: 0; bottom: 0; width: 45px; height: 45px;"src="resources/{{equipment.EquipmentStatus.StatusPhoto}}">
               <p>Status: {{equipment.EquipmentStatus.StatusName}}</p>
             </a>
         <div>
      </ion-content>
      <button class="button button-float button-positive" ng-click="showOptions()">
        <i class="icon ion-plus"></i>
      </button>
</body>
```

[image: Here is what it looks like with above code]

But when more objects are added or objects are removed, the button moves. I need it to stay at the very bottom of the screen, not on top of an object like shown and also not move at all.

What am I doing wrong within my styling?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Set css position to fix like below,

```
<style>
  .button-float{
    z-index: 12;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 15px;
    right: 15px;
    border-radius: 50% !important;
}
  </style>
```

Comment: It is stil in the same position as the above image. I need it to be in the bottom right of the screen.

Comment: Fixed it. I moved the button above `<ion-content>`